# Move to next inpute field on keyup inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table with several inputs in 1 row inside `td`. I need to jump to next input on keyup of any number. My code is working without `table` tag and stop working if i add `table` tag. Here is the link and code [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Orik3ll0/8xf5obq7/1/)

```js
$(".transition").keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    $(this).next('.transition').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="border-box"><input class="border-box transition" type="text" name="d1" placeholder="X" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*" value=""></td>
      <td class="border-box"><input class="border-box transition" type="text" name="d2" placeholder="X" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*" value=""></td>
      <td class="border-box"><input class="border-box transition" type="text" name="d3" placeholder="X" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*" value=""></td>
      <td class="border-box"><input class="border-box transition" type="text" name="d4" placeholder="X" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*" value=""></td>
      <td class="border-box"><input class="border-box transition" type="text" name="d5" placeholder="X" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*" value=""></td>
      <td class="border-box"><input class="border-box transition" type="text" name="d6" placeholder="X" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*" value=""></td>
      <td class="border-box"><input class="border-box transition" type="text" name="d7" placeholder="X" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.next('.transition')` looks for a sibling, and since the `input`'s are not, being the only child of their `td`s, which by the way are siblings, it won't work.

Instead do like this, where you get its `.parent()` then use `next()` to get the next `td` and finally `.find('.transition')` to find the `input`

```
$(this).parent().next().find('.transition').focus();
```

Stack snippet

```js
$(".transition").keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    $(this).parent().next().find('.transition').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="border-box"><input class="border-box transition" type="text" name="d1" placeholder="X" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*" value=""></td>
      <td class="border-box"><input class="border-box transition" type="text" name="d2" placeholder="X" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*" value=""></td>
      <td class="border-box"><input class="border-box transition" type="text" name="d3" placeholder="X" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*" value=""></td>
      <td class="border-box"><input class="border-box transition" type="text" name="d4" placeholder="X" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*" value=""></td>
      <td class="border-box"><input class="border-box transition" type="text" name="d5" placeholder="X" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*" value=""></td>
      <td class="border-box"><input class="border-box transition" type="text" name="d6" placeholder="X" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*" value=""></td>
      <td class="border-box"><input class="border-box transition" type="text" name="d7" placeholder="X" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ir works perfect!) thank you very much! Do dou know how can i set in text type of input only numbers and move to next inpute only if typed number 0-9?

Comment: @Orik00 Maybe like this `input type="number"` .... and for your script check the `event.keyCode` to see if it was a number before move to next

Comment: in this case `input type="number"` there are arrows in input, but i do not need them

Comment: @Orik00 Check previous comment...added how-to using the script